# Why should the right-censored observation be excluded from demonimator in KM estimation

Tags: censoring, kaplan-meier

It is well acknowledged that we cannot extrapolate the lifespan T of the censored observation.

In the Kaplan-Meier estimation, the estimated $s(t)$ for $t∈[t_j,t_{j+1}]$ is estimated using:
$$\hat{S}(t)=\prod_{i:t_i\leq t}\left(1-\frac{d_i}{n_i}\right)$$

I am confused by the fact that the censored observation is excluded from the denominator n at the next event point. Since we are not sure if their lifespan is more than the observed lifespan, how could we treat them as dead during the past interval?